# integrate an external app in django taking the code from any folder

Tags: python, django, external, django-apps

I want to install the external app [django-disqus](http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) in my blog. However, instead of install the module in the system via pip install or python setup.py install, I would like to download the code to a specific folder called libs and then link it to my project.

My folder structure is like this:

```
-root_folder
    -- project (here I have settings.py, urls.py and wsgi.py)
    -- blog (here I have models.py, admin.py, urls.py, templatetags/, template/)
    -- libs (here I want to add the code of disqus)
```

If I downloaded the code in libs, how can I link it to INSTALLED_APPS in setting.py?

Note: I run django 1.8

Comment: And why exactly would you want that!?

Comment: jajajaja, that's a good question @knbk, the real reason is because I would like to upload to my repository all disqus code with the license included. I don't like to depend on many external installations if possible

Comment: Also I'm a strange guy:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to register it the same way you'd register any django app.

Make libs a package by adding `__init__.py` file

Then add it to your settings.INSTALLED_APPS

`INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
     'libs.disqus',
 )`